# Why does my Flutter project fail with a Gradle build exception on 'E:\ali\flutter1\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\build.gradle.kts' line: 10?

Tags: flutter, dart, gradle

I'm encountering a build failure in my Flutter project, and the error points to the build file 'E:\ali\flutter1\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\build.gradle.kts' at line 10. The specific error message mentions a preference for settings repositories over project repositories, with the addition of the 'Google' repository in the 'app\build.gradle' file. Can anyone help me understand and resolve this issue?

[This error when run code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9H9E.png)

I attempted to run the code, but it resulted in a failure with the given exception. I considered running with the '--stacktrace', '--info', and '--debug' options, as well as '--scan' for more insights, but none of these options provided a clear solution. I'm seeking guidance on how to troubleshoot and fix this Gradle build error in Flutter.

Comment: Can you show your **android -> build.gradle** code